# How to create a method with a parameter that can be any type of variable?

Tags: java, function, parameters

I'm sorry if this is already asked but here is my question.  I would like to create a function where the parameter that the user inputs can be any variable type, similar to `System.out.println()`.

That being said how would I create that method?

```
public static void example(String, int, double, etc.) {
    //Code here
}
```

Comment: Do you want to overload it or change the parameters to `Object`?

Comment: @user1587985 "var cannot be resolved to a type"

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? Possible XY question...

Comment: @ZoveGames What should I do, what does object do, if object means all variables sure.  I'm familiar with overloading and would prefer not to.

Comment: Ok then, just change the parameter types to Object

Comment: @ZoveGames Thanks man! Quick reply too! Really appreciate it!  (Sorry for nooby question, been using Java for about a week.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change all the method parameters types to Object.

```
public void myMethod(Object o){
    // ...
}
```

Please note that in order to access `o` as a certain type of other class you will need to first test if it is in fact that class with `if(o instanceof OtherClass)` and then cast it with `OtherClass o2=(OtherClass) o`. Casting is expensive (hogs a lot of CPU (for a simple operation)) though so avoid if possible. If you just need a string representation of `o` then just call `o.toString()`.